# Blurry map tiles at start of android app based on google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, blurry

I have an app including a Google Map APIv2.

**After starting the app the map tiles are blurry. (sometimes just some parts)**

The tiles are getting sharp, only when the user moves the mapview a little.

Moving the mapview by code does **not** solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anyone agree with me, that this looks like a bug of the Maps Api v2?

Answer (score 5):

I has similar issue where the map would render blurry/low fidelity until I dragged the map with finger.

The issue I think was because I was updating the map with `googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);` once every second but I wasn't taking into account previous calls to `animateCamera` and whether the map was still animating.

The fix was to let use `GoogleMap.CancelableCallback` to find out when the animation had finished before calling `animateCamera()` again.

```
 GoogleMap.CancelableCallback cancelableCallback = new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            animationInProgress = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            animationInProgress = false;
        }
    };

        if(!animationInProgress){
            animationInProgress = true;
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), cancelableCallback);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your network connectivity is fine, then this issue should be due to caching of bad map data. You can clear the cache in google play service by going to Settings>Application>Google Play Service>Clear Cache and then try again.

Comment: Does not work. Even if this would work, I don't want to tell my users to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have given the Opposite latitude longitude to update the camera position